# zend framework 2 and doctrine query builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, query-builder

I am trying to write a query using the doctrine query builder based on the parameters i am getting from an array.

Here's my array,

```
$query = array('field' => 'number,
                            'from' => '1',
                                'to'  => '100',
                                    'Id' => '2',
                                        'Decimation' => '10'
                           );
```

The query that i am trying to write is,

> `select * from table where (number between 1  AND 100) AND (Id = 2) AND number mod 10 = 0`

Here's where i stand now,

```
if (is_array($parameters['query'])) {
        $queryBuilder->select()
                      ->where(
                              $queryBuilder->expr()->between($parameters['query']['field'], $parameters['query']['from'], $parameters['query']['to']),
                              $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('Id', '=?1'),
                              $queryBuilder->expr()->eq($parameters['query']['field'],'mod 10 = 0') 
                            )
                     ->setParameter(array(1 => $parameters['query']['Id']));
    }
```

I just cant wrap my head around this for some reason. Help !! anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested or anything, just directly typed into SO answer box:

```
$queryBuilder->select('table')
    ->from('My\Table\Entity', 'table')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->between('table.number', ':from', ':to'),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq->('table.id', ':id'),
    ))
    ->andWhere('MOD(table.number, :decimation) = 0')
    ->setParameters(array(
        'from' => $parameters['query']['from'],
        'to' => $parameters['query']['to'],
        'id' => $parameters['query']['id'],
        'decimation' => $parameters['query']['decimation']
   ));
```

It does not dynamically let you set which field to apply the where condition to. However, this is most likely a bad idea without whitelisting the values you want to allow. Once this is done a simple modification to the code above (just interpolate the value in place of `number` in the `table.number` string).

Answer (score 0):

I kinda got it,

The main idea here was to use the andWhere clause. Multiple where clauses was what i wanted. and the mod operator that doctrine gives. Worked out pretty well. In between the requirement changed as well.

Comment: Did you even check my answer that describes exactly this?